# Wordpress / add several Inputs in own Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, list, input, repeater

In my input-field i can add data to "options.php", and display it. But how can i generate a second/third/... inputfield by clicking on an button (for example: "add new") and safe this data in "options.php"?

```
function ww_contact_new_page() {
?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'ww-contact-settings-group' );
    do_settings_sections( 'ww-contact-settings-group' ); ?>
    <input type="text" name="ww_contact_name" placeholder="/impressum" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('ww_contact_name') ); ?>" />
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
<?php}

/* Register */
function register_ww_contact_settings() {
register_setting( 'ww-contact-settings-group', 'ww_contact_name' );}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use a framework like [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) to do the heavy lifting for you

> CMB2 is a developer's toolkit for building metaboxes, custom fields,
>   and forms for WordPress that will blow your mind.

You can create groups of inputs and repeat them or create groups with repeated inputs

```
<?php

$group_field_id = $cmb->add_field(array(
    'id'          => 'wiki_test_repeat_group',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'description' => __('Generates reusable form entries', 'cmb2'),
    'repeatable'  => false, 
    'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __('Entry {#}', 'cmb2'), 
        'add_button'    => __('Add Another Entry', 'cmb2'),
        'remove_button' => __('Remove Entry', 'cmb2'),
        'sortable'      => true,
    ),
));

$cmb->add_group_field($group_field_id, array(
    'name' => 'Entry Title',
    'id'   => 'title',
    'type' => 'text',
    'repeatable' => true,
));
```

See also [Using CMB to create an Admin Theme Options Page](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Using-CMB-to-create-an-Admin-Theme-Options-Page)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. And how can i display (in this example "title") in the frontend?

Comment: @Bavaria see [Display the Metadata](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage#display-the-metadata)

Comment: so i tried this, but it did not work.
`code`
$text = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'title', true );

// Echo the metadata
echo esc_html( $text );
`code`

Comment: I can get the data from a field with: "$my_plugin_group_title = my_plugin_get_option( 'test_text' );". But this only works for a regular field (created with "add_field"). How can i get the data from field inside a Group (created with "add_group_field")?

Comment: @Bavaria please read the [documentation](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki) . everything is explained in details , if you have a new question please ask new one on StackOverflow